# Php Page not complete select list. it gets truncated at the top of screen

Tags: html, css, select

[image: select list get truncated]

As you can see that there is values in the select dropdown but it is not showing and even scroll is not visible.

What do i do to see scroll bar?
i tired adding

```
style="overflow-y:scroll;"
```

but it didn't help.
I am using this online page on touch monitor without keyboard and mouse hence not getting scrollbar creates a problem.

Kindly help..

Comment: I think this is a browser problem.. which browser do you use?

Comment: the value `scroll` means truncating the element and the browser SHOULD display a scroll bar. Give the values `visible` or `auto` a try maybe.

Comment: not this is also not working..

Comment: Do you have an `overflow: hidden` on an ancestor element?  That could also truncate the element.